# Axios statusText is always empty

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, exception, axios

I've been using axios recently but I can't get the error message thrown by Spring Boot RuntimeException.

I've created a simple `RuntimeException` which throws 404 status:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I make a GET request to one of my endpoint where all it does is throw the `BadRequestException` with some message:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/throw")
    public ResponseEntity<?> throwError() {
        throw new BadRequestException("This text should be in statusText");
    }
}
```

`console.log()` from the catch clause (`.catch((error) => console.log(error.response))`) is:
[image]

As you can see, the `statusText` is just an empty string, where `"This text should be in statusText"` should be expected.

Using `fetch()` works perfectly fine, but switching from `axios` to `fetch` in my situation will be time-wasting.

Am I missing something? Do I even throw the exceptions with my messages correctly?

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: what have you tried in the frontend?

Comment: afai can tell from the pic, the information has gone inside the `data` object instead

Comment: ```
    request.get('http://localhost:8080/throw')
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.data));
```
 this is literally the whole code on the frontend.
`error.data` is undefined

Comment: can you check inside `error.response.data`?

Comment: in the `error.response.data` there's only `error`, `path`, `status`, and `timestamp`. Nothing about the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is Spring Boot set a `server.error.include-message` as `never` by default. Setting it to `always` returns the message in a response.

Answer (score 0):

Note that HTTP/2 doesn't support status text messages, so you'll always get an empty one on a HTTP/2 connection (often this means you get them in development but they're empty in production). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText